# conversion of np.array(dtype='str') in an np.array(dtype='datetime')

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, numpy

I need to transform the string values within an `np.array` into datetime values. The string values contain the following format: ('%Y%m%d').

#### My test data:

```
date_str = np.array([['20121002', '20121002', '20121002'],
                     ['20121003', '20121003', '20121003'],
                     ['20121004', '20121004', '20121004']])
```

I try to convert this array with the `pandas` library.

#### My code:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.to_datetime(date_str, format="%d%m%Y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DataFrame, then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to it [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
In [68]: pd.DataFrame(date_str).apply(pd.to_datetime)
Out[68]: 
           0          1          2
0 2012-10-02 2012-10-02 2012-10-02
1 2012-10-03 2012-10-03 2012-10-03
2 2012-10-04 2012-10-04 2012-10-04
```

In order to verify the type of the result, here's the type of the first column, for example:

```
In [73]: pd.DataFrame(date_str).apply(pd.to_datetime).iloc[:, 0].dtype
Out[73]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Comment: thank you for your awnser. It works really fine even with integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each element of the array to a [pandas series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html), and perform the [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) operation.

```
In [81]: [pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(x), format="%Y%m%d") for x in date_str]
Out[81]: 
[0   2012-10-02
 1   2012-10-02
 2   2012-10-02
 dtype: datetime64[ns], 0   2012-10-03
 1   2012-10-03
 2   2012-10-03
 dtype: datetime64[ns], 0   2012-10-04
 1   2012-10-04
 2   2012-10-04
 dtype: datetime64[ns]]
```